# Processing dataframe with conditionals, using df.apply

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have a catalog of trees, which I've imported into a dataframe. It looks like this:

```
>>> df
   ID    Tree  Zone  Temp_Limit Grade
0   1   Apple     1          21     A
1   2   Apple     1          21     B
2   3  Orange     3          28     B
3   4    Pear     2          26     A
4   5   Apple     4          24     C
```

The idea is that depending on the type of tree, zone, and temp_limit, the dosage for irrigation, fertilizers, estimated transplant date, etc. would be calculated. Those would be additional columns in the dataframe.

The problem is that the formulas are conditional. It's not just "multiply temp limit by 5 and add 4", more like "if it's an apple tree in zone 2, apply this formula, if it's an orange tree in zone 1, formula goes like this... etc"

And to make things a bit more complicated, there might be rows that have an ID, a Tree type, and no data, that correspond to trees that haven't been delivered, etc.

My current solution is to use df.apply and have a function to do the conditionals and skip the blank rows:

```
def calculate_irrigation(species,zone,templimit,grade):
 if species.lower() == "apple":
  if zone == 3:
   etc etc etc

df['irrigation'] = df.apply (lambda x: calculate_irrigation(x['Tree'], x['Zone'], x['Temp_limit'], x['Grade'])
```

Question: is a Dataframe and df.apply the best solution for this? I used a df because it adapts very well to the data I'm working with and getting the data in there is pretty straightforward. Plus exporting the final results is easy. But when you have to do different operations based on values, and have to start putting functions in there, it makes you wonder if there's a better way you're not seeing.

Comment: It seems to me this question is more suited to be asked in the  [Code Review Forum](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).  Code Review is a question and answer site for peer programmer code reviews. Please read the relevant guidance related to how to properly ask questions on this site before posting your question.

Comment: we can't really answer with `etc etc etc`, show the full real code